# Best data base to allow queries from web page

Tags: database, web-server

I have a 500k row R data table with about 25 columns.  I want to build a website that allows visitors to query the data using about 5 of the 25 columns using drop downs.

What's the best data base tool that has the flexibility to scale from, e.g., 100 users to e.g., 5,000 users?

Of course, I'd prefer something that's open source/free. But willing to buy if a better match and feature rich.

The data base would grow each quarter by three to five cols and 300k to 500k rows. I imagine using a separate table that would be "joined".

A query would return between 1 and 2k rows.

Comment: Are you talking about 5000 *concurrent* users? Or 5000 registered users each of which might not use the service at all? In any case for any *commercial* package that enables you to configure so many users you'll probably pay large license fees. And even for open-source software you'll probably need some sort of support.

Comment: 5000 concurrent.  I can envision 100k registered users. I can only guess re: concurrent users b/w 500 and 5000.   Access will be free so I can likely throttle performance to deal somewhat with demand and peaks but I have no idea what the user experience will be.  THat's why I'm asking for experienced insight and suggestions.